# How to debootstrap ubuntu 13.04 on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: apt, 13.04, arm, 23.04, debootstrap

I'm trying to debootstrap ubuntu 13.04 raring for armhf on the root partition of one of my sd cards,mounted on /mnt/sdj4 ,so I tried like this :

```
# debootstrap --arch=armhf --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg --verbose --foreign raring rootfs https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu-archive/

I: Retrieving InRelease

I: Retrieving Release

E: Failed getting release file https://mirror.math.princeton.edu/pub/ubuntu-archive/dists/raring/Release
```

or

```
# debootstrap --arch=armhf --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg --verbose --foreign raring rootfs http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring

I: Retrieving InRelease

I: Retrieving Release

E: Failed getting release file http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/dists/raring/Release
```

how to fix it ?

PS : Don't worry,I will not use this old ubuntu version,I need it only for a little amount of time,just to study a specific situation.

Comment: Going by the second error, the URL you should be using is `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`

Comment: worked. thanks.

Comment: BTW, why do you need 13.04? Is there a specific version of specific software you are trying to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/)